Azure Data Factory Not Incorrectly Previewing Data
We have a situation where ADF will not preview that actual data in Excel spreadsheet. As you can see there is data in the excel spreadsheet, but when we preview it no data appears in the preview.

Our dataset is as follows. You will notice that where are connecting to an .xlsx spreadsheet. To preview the data we insert the sheetName as the parameter, but nothing appears

Our json Dataset looks like the following. You will notice, there aren't any options to change the range:
{
    "name": "wwpRater_source_excel",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "agrlatitudelivestorage",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "sheetName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "wwpRater/Source"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Excel",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sheetName": {
                "value": "@dataset().sheetName",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": "wwpRater.xlsx",
                "folderPath": "wwp-rater",
                "fileSystem": "bronze-silver"
            },
            "firstRowAsHeader": true
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}

I have attached the dataset to a copy activity, see image below, however I'm still not able to preview the data


You are giving sheet name as dynamic, that may be the reason to get it.

@Bhavani, I'm not sure what you mean by giving the sheetname as Dynamic

Are you suggesting that we map the fields

Are you previewing data at dataset level or any activity level?

Once try select sheet name manually, without using parameter, let me know the preview data is working or not?

Go to dataset Json and check the range option as shown below:
"typeProperties": {
            "sheetName": {
                "value": "@dataset().Sheet",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": "second.xlsx",
                "fileSystem": "dec20excels"
            },
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "Range": "A1:B1"
        }

Even though the rang is mentioned as "A1:B1" it is showing as below:

While previewing the data getting as below:

Remove the range from Json and try previewing data, you will get the data as shown below:


Hi @Bhavani, that's for once again getting in touch. I have updated the question showing the JSON for the Dataset. There aren't any properties for the range

I also tried selecting manually without parameter and I still couldn't see the preview.

Hi @Bhavani, do you have any other thoughts?

I absolutely cannot get this to work for me. So if anyone has any thoughts it would be most welcomed

Once attach your dataset to copy activity and try to preview the data from it.

thanks for gettting in touch I have updated the question to show that I attached our dataset to a copy activity, but still unable to preview the data

Are you getting any error in copy activity?

Hi @Bhavani, we aren't getting any error in the copy activity

Then it may be issue with your data factory, raise support ticket.

Hi @Bhavani, that is so strange that you don't get any problems with your ADF

Yes, I am not getting any issue, if possible, provide your excel file, I will try with your data?

Hi @Bhavani, attached is the excel file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nPp3RBAcpNyrC1k70t0QKz256QYqtUam/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100499765373192824033&rtpof=true&sd=true

Hi @Bhavani, did you have any luck with the Excel file?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
